# Where to find a statistics on different Mac OS X version distribution

Tags: macos

I found this post having statistics for the different OS X version distribution from April 2013:
http://chitika.com/os-x-version-distribution

Does anyone knows a newer statistic on this topic? I was not able to find anything using Google.

Comment: I’m not sure this is a good question for Stack Overflow. That said, [The Omni Group](http://update.omnigroup.com) and [Adium](https://sparkle.adium.im) publish user base stats.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some of the larger OS X software vendors generate statistics from their update mechanisms.
E.g. the Omni Group provides this web page: http://update.omnigroup.com

You can switch to "Overall, major" to see a graph describing the adoption rate of major OS X versions.

Comment: And now, the data. Mmmmm, data.